# Corporate site search

Tags: web-services, search, web, full-text-search

Having a small, SEO-friendly corporate site behind a basic password protection scheme, I'd like to add a basic search facility by using one of the off-the-shelf solutions. (I don't mind Google, or Yahoo having the site's content, as long as it doesn't leak to the web).

[Google doesn't seem to support](http://www.google.com/support/customsearch/bin/answer.py?answer=72365) this, so I'd like to ask the SO community for recommendations, and pros/cons of each (preferably free) solution? (Rolling my own is the least prefered solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia has a nice list of [Enterprise Search Vendors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_enterprise_search_vendors) which links to information about each of them.  It's a bit difficult to recommend certain ones without knowing what breadth of features you are looking for past text indexing.

[Xapian](http://xapian.org/) is one of the free solutions that is readily availible to integrate with your existing applications in several languages, they also have [Omega](http://xapian.org/docs/omega/overview.html) which is a packaged search solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run PHP on your site, Wrensoft's [Zoom Search Engine](http://www.wrensoft.com/zoom/) is pretty good.  It's free for sites under 50 pages, and cheap for larger sites.  I use it for my site at http://entrian.com/source-search/ if you want to see it in action.  (I'm not affiliated with Wrensoft - just a happy user.)